# ruby .split('\n') not splitting on new line

Tags: ruby, string

Why does this string not split on each "\n"? (RUBY)

```
"ADVERTISING [7310]\n\t\tIRS NUMBER:\t\t\t\t061340408\n\t\tSTATE OF INCORPORATION:\t\t\tDE\n\t\tFISCAL YEAR END:\t\t\t0331\n\n\tFILING VALUES:\n\t\tFORM TYPE:\t\t10-Q\n\t\tSEC ACT:\t\t1934 Act\n\t".split('\n')
>> ["ADVERTISING [7310]\n\t\tIRS NUMBER:\t\t\t\t061340408\n\t\tSTATE OF INCORPORATION:\t\t\tDE\n\t\tFISCAL YEAR END:\t\t\t0331\n\n\tFILING VALUES:\n\t\tFORM TYPE:\t\t10-Q\n\t\tSEC ACT:\t\t1934 Act\n\t"]
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You need `.split("\n")`. String interpolation is needed to properly interpret the new line, and double quotes are one way to do that.

Answer (score 44):

In Ruby single quotes around a string means that escape characters are not interpreted. Unlike in C, where single quotes denote a single character. In this case `'\n'` is actually equivalent to `"\\n"`.

So if you want to split on `\n` you need to change your code to use double quotes.

`.split("\n")`

Answer (score 24):

Ruby has the methods `String#each_line` and `String#lines`

returns an enum:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-each_line

returns an array:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-lines

I didn't test it against your scenario but I bet it will work better than manually choosing the newline chars.

Comment: But to note that `#lines` will not remove the newline character, while `#split` will do that: 

`"a\nb".lines => ["a\n", "b"]` while `"a\nb".split("\n") => ["a", "b"]`

Comment: Also, for files read in text mode (the default), newline sequences are translated to `"\n"` ([see](https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/12/14/ruby-code-on-windows/#orgheadline14)). So no need to choose them manually. Use `"\n"` across platforms.

Answer (score 12):

Or a regular expression

```
.split(/\n/)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use single quotes for this:

```
"ADVERTISING [7310]\n\t\tIRS NUMBER:\t\t\t\t061340408\n\t\tSTATE OF INCORPORATION:\t\t\tDE\n\t\tFISCAL YEAR END:\t\t\t0331\n\n\tFILING VALUES:\n\t\tFORM TYPE:\t\t10-Q\n\t\tSEC ACT:\t\t1934 Act\n\t".split("\n")
```